# Is there a way to prevent the Python sh module from escaping a regex passed to grep?

Tags: python, grep

I'm attempting to call grep with a modestly complex regular expression using the sh module in Python.  However, on running my script, I'm finding that sh seems to be escaping the regular expression for me, resulting in a garble regex.  How can I prevent it from doing that?

Here's my code:

```
import sh

print sh.grep("/\@\S+\(/", "-r", "--include='*.php'")
```

Results in it running:

```
RAN: "/bin/grep /\\@\\S+\\(/ -r --include='*.php'"
```

Which, obviously, throws errors.  Is there anyway to get it to not quote the regex, or is that just a bug in the module?

Comment: What version of sh are you using / what version of python?

Comment: Python version 2.7.5, sh version 1.0.9

Comment: I think be default the error statement for RAN will use the double backslash, but the actual grep run won't. I tried running a statement with just plain text search for MY_TEXT, and with \\(MY_TEXT\\) , and both produced the same results. If the double slash was included the \\\( would have failed. I even purposely screwed up the call to get the ran, and the double slashes were there.

Comment: ```print sh.grep(r"/\@\S+\(/", "-r", "--include='*.php'")```

Comment: note the leading 'r' declares the regex string as a 'raw' string which escapes being escaped